# Impossible to trigger the "BackButton" in Android Lollipop with Phonegap/Cordova

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-build

In my Cordova App for Android, I add the following code to manage the "Backbutton" :

```
document.addEventListener("backbutton", onBackKeyDown, false);

function onBackKeyDown() {
    // Do Stuff 
}
```

When I use:

```
cordova run android --device
```

I can trigger the "Backbutton".

When I use:

```
cordova build android
```

And release on Google Play. I can't trigger the "Backbutton" anymore.

My device is a LG G3 and I am on Lollipop.

Comment: did you put the addEventListener after the deviceready event?

Comment: Yes and I tested that the device ready works well.

Comment: Did you consider dispatchEvent()?  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events

Comment: Have you tried checking for console errors using Chrome Inspect?

Comment: Everything works fine in chrome.

Comment: I will try dispatchEvent(). Thanks.